# How do I generate SVG sprites with GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, gatsby

In my `gatsby-browser.js` file, I have two imports that look similar to:

```
@import npm-package/lib/icons.svg
@import npm-package/lib/icons-rich.svg
```

My current `gatsby-node.js` file is as follows

```
const path = require('path')
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin')

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig()

  config.resolve.alias = {
    ...config.resolve.alias,
     /// aliases working fine
  }

  config.module.rules = [
    ...config.module.rules,
    {
      test: /(icons|icons-rich).svg$/,
      loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
      options: {
        extract: true,
        publicPath: './'
      },
    },
  ],

    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,
      new SpriteLoaderPlugin()
    ]

  actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)
}
```

When I run `gatsby develop`, I get the following error:

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/svg-sprite-loader/lib/loader.js):
svg-sprite-loader exception. Some loaders will be applied after svg-sprite-loader in extract mode
```

and no files are ever output.

When i run `gatsby build`, I get a `sprite.svg` file output to the `public` directory but it doesn't seem like the svg sprite gets added to the html document body.

1) How do I get the `gatsby develop` command to process and output the svg to the proper directory

2) I suspect the issue with `gatsby build` is related to the svg file i'm trying include in the html document, which is in my `Layout.jsx` file and looks like

```
<Icon icon="all" iconPath="./public/sprite.svg" />
```

I would guess the `./public/sprite.svg` is missing for some reason but I can't figure out what the correct file path is (tried everything except the right thing apparently).